# Why my attempt to global syncronization does not work?

Tags: opencl

I try to use this code.
But kernel exits after executing cycle only once.

If I remove "while(...)" line - cycle works, but results of course are mess.
If I state "volatile __global uint *g_barrier" it freezes a PC with black screen for a while and then program deadlocks.

```
__kernel void Some_Kernel(__global uint *g_barrier)
{
    uint i, t;

    for (i = 1; i < MAX; i++) {

        // some useful code here

        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
        if (get_local_id(0) == 0) atomic_add(g_barrier, 1);
        t = i*get_num_groups(0);
        while(*g_barrier < t); // try to sync it all
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be expecting all work groups to be scheduled to run in parallel. OpenCL does not guarantee this to happen. Some work groups may not start until some other work groups have entirely completed running the kernel.

Moreover, barriers only synchronise *within* a work group. Atomic operations on global memory are atomic with regard to other work groups too, but there is no guarantee about order.

If you need other work groups to complete some code before running some other code, you will need to enqueue each of those chunks of work separately on a serial command queue (or appropriately connect them using events on an out-of-order queue). So for your example code, you need to remove your `for` and `while` loops, and enqueue your kernel `MAX-1` times and pass `i` as a kernel argument.

Depending on the capabilities of your device and the size of your data set, your other option is to submit only one large work group, though this is unlikely to give you good performance unless you have a lot of such smaller tasks which are independent from one another.

(I will point out that there is a good chance your question suffers from [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have not stated the overall problem your code is trying to solve. So there may be better solutions than the ones I have suggested.)

Comment: So the main point, If there are too many work groups - they executes in some series. I cannot expect ALL of them to work in parallel?

Comment: @sdml You can't rely on **any** to run in parallel. And conversely, you can't rely on them to run sequentially, or in any particular order either. It's entirely up to the implementation how they are scheduled. You can only rely on work items *within* a group to run more or less in parallel. For work items within a group, use barriers to act as sync points, because again you can't rely on any particular scheduling method. (For example, on GPUs, some number of work items in a group *typically* run in lock-step; but you don't know how many, or if a device uses some other model.)